# HTML-find in page and display ONLY relevant portion

Tags: html

Ok, the title may sound a bit easy or common but my problem is not that easier. I'm working on making a HTML page that displays a database in table rows. A sample code is:

```
<table>
<tr><td>ABC Hospitals</td></tr>
<tr><td>India</td><td>Contact:9999999999</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td>XYZ Blood Bank</td></tr>
<tr><td>NewJersey</td><td>Contact:8888888888</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td>ABC Inn</td></tr>
<tr><td>California</td><td>Contact:7777777777</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have used tables to group data, with each one containing rows to display data. The code gives the following output sample, with the CSS effects added:
[Image1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BypBZDSrbKjhQ3pGZmg1VmxVc2s/view?usp=sharing) - Sorry, I'm a new user and StackOverflow doesn't allow me to post images.

I'm now in requirement of a 'Find in page' box to search the HTML document for a specific piece of information(say "ABC"). The search must display ONLY the table(s) that contains the query term("ABC"), in our case, hiding ALL other tables which do not contain the search term. I have achieved the sample output by manually editing the HTML, just to more clearly show my requirement. I'm in need of the JScript(or any appropriate) code to achieve the result:
[Image2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BypBZDSrbKjhZHM4am1PVDR6eUE/view?usp=sharing) - Sorry again.

I'm sure somebody here will be able to help me, either provide me some code piece or guiding me to some useful link. Thanks in advance.

-Sriram

Comment: Regardless of the actual question, have a look at the `<caption>` and `<th>` elements when working with tables.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: So far I can highlight the matches but filtering the tables as a whole - I don't have any idea how to implement that using JavaScript.

Comment: For this type of DOM manipulation you might find it helpful to get yourself acquainted with jQuery. JavaScript solutions are possible but are just a bit harder to write (and to read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var search = document.querySelector('#search');
var database = document.querySelector('#database');

search.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    // Every time the input changes, execute filterMatching.
    filterMatching(search.value, database);
});

function filterMatching(value, parent) {
    // Get the parent's children into an array
    var children = [].slice.call(parent.children);
    // Everything is shown by default.
    children.forEach(function removeHiddenFromAll(child) {
        child.classList.remove('hidden');
    });
    // Find those who are not matching
    children.filter(function findNonMatching(child) {
        // the toLowerCase() on both ensures the search is not case sensitive.
        return child.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) < 0;
    })
    // After we found all the non matching, hide them
    .forEach(function hideNonMatching(nonMatching) {
        nonMatching.classList.add('hidden');
    });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div id="database">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ABC Hospitals</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>Contact:9999999999</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>XYZ Blood Bank</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NewJersey</td>
            <td>Contact:8888888888</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ABC Inn</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>California</td>
            <td>Contact:7777777777</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work in the snippet but not in my actual code. Am I right in placing the whole of the JS code(the first part - from var search= ... to the corresponding } ) inside the <script>..</script> tag? Sorry I'm still a student

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, for some reason, the thing doesn't work when the element are stored as 'var' types. So I modified the code slightly as follows: I created a new function:

```
function fn_search(){
var phrase = document.querySelector('#search').value;
filterMatching(phrase, document.querySelector('#database'));
}
```

and called

```
<input type="text" id="search" oninput="fn_search()" />
```

The program now works fine.

The complete code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table{
    padding: 20px;
   margin: 10px;
   background: #990030;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 17px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 1.3em;
   border: 2px dashed #9ff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #990030, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
   text-shadow: -1px -1px #aa3030;
   font-weight: normal;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 325px;
height:75px;
}
th, td {

    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
}
table.hidden {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>

function fn_search(){
var phrase = document.querySelector('#search').value; 
filterMatching(phrase, document.querySelector('#database'));
}

function filterMatching(value, parent) {
    // Get the parent's children into an array
    var children = [].slice.call(parent.children);
    // Everything is shown by default.
    children.forEach(function removeHiddenFromAll(child) {
        child.classList.remove('hidden');
    });
    // Find those who are not matching
    children.filter(function findNonMatching(child) {
        // the toLowerCase() on both ensures the search is not case sensitive.
        return child.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) < 0;
    })
    // After we found all the non matching, hide them
    .forEach(function hideNonMatching(nonMatching) {
        nonMatching.classList.add('hidden');
    });
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="search" oninput="fn_search()" />
<div id="database">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ABC Hospitals</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>Contact:9999999999</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>XYZ Blood Bank</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NewJersey</td>
            <td>Contact:8888888888</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ABC Inn</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>California</td>
            <td>Contact:7777777777</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```